# Kryo class error in Apache-Spark

Tags: class, apache-spark, broadcast, kryo

I have some Spark code and I use Kryo serialization. When no server fails everything runs fine, but when a server fails, I come across some big issues as it tries to recover itself. Basically the error message says that my `Article` class becomes unknown to a server.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 29 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 29.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 316, DATANODE-3): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: $line50.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Article
        com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
        com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
        com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
        com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:721)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:133)
        org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:133)
        org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
        org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:235)
        org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:163)
        org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:70)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:227)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really have a lot of trouble understanding what I am doing wrong...

I declare these classes outside of my maps

```
case class Contrib ( contribType: Option[String], surname: Option[String], givenNames: Option[String], phone: Option[String], email: Option[String], fax: Option[String] )

// Class to hold references
case class Reference( idRef:Option[String], articleNameRef:Option[String], pmIDFrom: Option[Long], pmIDRef:Option[Long])

// Class to hold articles
case class Article(articleName:String, articleAbstract: Option[String],
                   pmID:Option[Long], doi:Option[String],
                   references: Iterator[Reference],
                   contribs: Iterator[Contrib],
                   keywords: List[String])
```

It seems that *some* executors just don't know what an `Article` is anymore... 
How can I resolve that issue?

Thanks,
Stephane

Comment: To clarify: which version of Spark are using?  Does this exception only occur on new executors that are added after the initial set of executors die?

Comment: Using Spark 1.1.0 on HDP 2.1 preview - Rackspace. 
It occurs really randomly (no executor dies). At first, at some point my NODE-3 forgets what "Article" is and gives me that error. All my executors are up at the same time when I create my spark-shell.